# SQL Server stored procedure does not return any values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure which doesn't return any values I run EXEC command

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GClient]
    @CLIENT_CODE INT = NULL output,
    @CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR = 50 output,
    @CATEGORY VARCHAR = 50 output,
    @ATC VARCHAR = 50 output
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        dbo.CLIENT
    WHERE
        CLIENT_CODE = @CLIENT_CODE OR 
        CLIENT_NAME = @CLIENT_NAME OR 
        CATEGORY = @CATEGORY OR
        ATC = @ATC; 
END
```

I execute it like this:

```
 DECLARE @client_name varchar(50)
 EXEC GCLIENT @client_name='rillera general merchandise'
```

There is a record on the table with that value, I don't why it doesn't return any records at all.

Comment: Do u have any input parameters at all ?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Right now, you parameters (without explicit length) are **all** defaulting a string of ***EXACTLY*** 1 character long - so you input parameter of `@client_name` is shortened to `r` and that's the value that's being searched in your table - no wonder it doesn't find anything!!

Comment: That's enlightening, thank you, I'm very new to SQL programming and all of your inputs are very important to me. I was now able to run my program properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your procedure with input parameter and assign columns to the output parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GClient]
@client_name varchar(50)
@CLIENT_CODE INT output,
@CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(50) output,
@CATEGORY VARCHAR(50) output,
@ATC VARCHAR(50) output

AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
@CLIENT_CODE = CLIENT_CODE, 
@CLIENT_NAME=CLIENT_NAME,
@CATEGORY = CATEGORY,
@ATC = ATC 
FROM 
 dbo.CLIENT
WHERE
client_name =@client_name 
END
```

Also your execution step is wrong, you need to declare the output parameters and call them with exec. For eg.

```
DECLARE @CLIENT_CODE varchar(50)
DECLARE @CLIENT_NAME varchar(50)
DECLARE @CATEGORY varchar(50)
DECLARE @ATC varchar(50)

EXEC GCLIENT 'rillera general merchandise', @CLIENT_CODE OUTPUT, 
@CLIENT_NAME OUTPUT, @CATEGORY OUTPUT, @ATC OUTPUT
```

Comment: It just says "Command Successful" and nothing else, I ran my webform and it still doesn't return any records

Answer (score 0):

Simply u can remove out put clause, as u have output columns specified in the table and give one input parameter

```
Create  PROCEDURE USP_GClient
@CLIENT_NAME varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    CLIENT_CODE
    ,CLIENT_NAME
    ,CATEGORY
    ,ATC
FROM 
     DBO.CLIENT
WHERE
    CLIENT_NAME=@CLIENT_NAME
END
```

and execute the proc

```
EXEC USP_GClient @CLIENT_NAME
```